# Runnig the same query over and over again

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I'm using Oracle SQL and I need help with hard query.

I have the following table (`MyTable`):

```
id int,
name1 int,
name2 int,
..
..
..
name80 int,
```

These column names are fake.

Here is my query:

```
select id ,cnt / (select count(*) from MyTable)
from(
  select id, name1, name2, count(distinct name1) over(partition by name2) cnt
from my MyTable);
```

I need to run this query each time for next pair of columns. For example, the next pair will be:

```
select id ,cnt / (select count(*) from MyTable)
from(
  select id, name2, name3, count(distinct name2) over(partition by name3) cnt
from my MyTable);
```

And so on.

The final output table need to include id and each pair calculation.

```
id int,
"calc of name1+name2" float,
"calc of name2+name3" float,
"calc of name3+name4" float,
"calc of name4+name5" float,
"calc of name5+name6" float,
...
...
...
"calc of name79+name80" float,
```

Can someone show me how to do that? I'll really appreciate any help. I'm feel lost.

Comment: `Can someone show me how to do that?` Someone will definitely be able to as soon as you provide sample of source data and desired output, better yet use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4).

Comment: All of the source data are int columns. The columns names are totally different each other. Is anything missing?

Comment: I'm a bit worried that you're doing this.  Why do you have 80 separate nesting levels - especially as columns?

Comment: Its and table data with 80 columns. Just it. It's not a nesting level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something?  You want a query like this:

```
select id,
       count(distinct name2) over (partition by name3) / count(*) over (),
       count(distinct name3) over (partition by name4) / count(*) over (),
       . . .
from mytable;
```

My guess is that your problem is typing all these rows.

You can run a query like this to generate the code:

```
select replace(replace('count(distinct <thiscol>) over (partition by <nextcol>) / count(*) over () as <thiscol>_<nextcol>,',
                       '<thiscol>', column_name
                      ), '<nextcol>', lead(column_name) over (order by column_id)
              )
from all_tab_columns atc
where table_name = 'mytable'
```

Comment: Gordon, you are too generous

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I can't explain why, but your query (the first one), doesn't return the same values as my query. Actually, your query always return the same value. Any idea why?

Comment: @Omri . . . No, I don't understand why.  `count(*) over ()` and `(select count(*) from mytable)` should return the same thing in this case -- there is no `group by` and no `where` clause.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I understand the issue. It was my fault. Now I'll check your solution and let you know the results. Thanks for that moment!

Comment: @GordonLinoff...I have another question - I want the same query, but to replace the order of the columns. I tried to replace <thiscol> with <nextcol>, and <nextcol> with <thiscol> , but the result was the same. Is it possible re change the order?

Comment: @Omri . . . Look at the`replace` logic.  Replace the column values with whichever column name you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...I understood the syntax of this function (easy syntax), but i didn’t manage to change your query. It’s a bit too complicated for a guy who just learned the function. Any chance for help? It would be awesome if you will add it above.

Comment: @omri . . . I can't see your code, but if you change the values in the pattern string for `replace()`, it should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I failed. I'm getting "too many argument" error. Any chance for help? I would be more than appreciate that.

Comment: @Omri . . . Ask another question and include the code you have written in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff..It's a bit problem for me to copy the code, since i'm working on a different machine, which is not connected to the internet (i'm not allowed to take data out of the server). I'm stressed out, since i have to finish it at the next hours, and i don't have enough time to copy my query (with fake column names). I will ask another question, but with your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ) and  USER_TAB_COLUMNS table for table column metadata.